# Callback at random times from a child process with infinite loop, and termination

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I need to react in a main process to random events happening in a child process. I have implemented this with a queue between the main and the child process, and a 'queue poller' running in a secondary thread of the main process and calling a callback function each time it finds an item in the queue. The code is below and seems to work.
Question 1: Could you please tell me if the strategy is correct or if something simpler exists ?
Question 2: I tried to have both the child process and the secondary thread terminated when stopping the main loop, but it fails, at least in spyder. What should I do to terminate everything properly?
Thanks for your help :-)

```
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep
from random import random

class MyChildProcess(Process):
    """
    This process runs as a child process of the main process.
    It fills a queue (instantiated in the main process - main thread) at random times.
    """
    def __init__(self,queue):
        super(MyChildProcess,self).__init__()
        self._q = queue             # memorizes the queue
        self._i = 0                 # attribute to be incremented and put in the queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self._q.put(self._i)    # puts in the queue
            self._i += 1            # increment for next time
            sleep(random())         # wait between 0 and 1s

class myListenerInSeparateThreadOfMainProcess():
    """
    This listener runs in a secondary thread of the main process.
    It polls a queue and calls back a function for each item found.
    """
    def __init__(self, queue, callbackFunction):
        self._q = queue              # memorizes the queue
        self._cbf = callbackFunction # memorizes the queue
        self.pollQueue()

    def pollQueue(self):
        while True:
            sleep(0.2)               # polls 5 times a second max
            self.readQueue()   

    def readQueue(self):
        while not self._q.empty():   # empties the queue each time
            self._cbf(self._q.get()) # calls the callback function for each item

def runListener(q,cbf):
    """Target function for the secondary thread"""
    myListenerInSeparateThreadOfMainProcess(q,cbf)    

def callBackFunc(*args):
    """This is my reacting function"""
    print 'Main process gets data from queue: ', args

if __name__ == '__main__':     
    q= Queue()
    t = Thread(target=runListener, args=(q,callBackFunc))
    t.daemon=True        # try to have the secondary thread terminated if main thread terminates
    t.start()
    p = MyChildProcess(q)
    p.daemon = True      # try to have the child process terminated if parent process terminates
    p.start()            # no target scheme and no parent blocking by join
    while True:          # this is the main application loop
        sleep(2)
        print 'In main loop doing something independant from the rest'
```

Here is what I get:

```
Main process gets data from queue:  (0,)
Main process gets data from queue:  (1,)
Main process gets data from queue:  (2,)
Main process gets data from queue:  (3,)
In main loop doing something independant from queue management
Main process gets data from queue:  (4,)
Main process gets data from queue:  (5,)
Main process gets data from queue:  (6,)
Main process gets data from queue:  (7,)
In main loop doing something independant from queue management
Main process gets data from queue:  (8,)
Main process gets data from queue:  (9,)
In main loop doing something independant from queue management
...
```

Answer (score 0):

General observations:

**class MyChildProcess**

You don't need to create separate classes for the child process and listener thread. Simple functions can work.

**pollQueue**

You can use a blocking get() call in the listener thread. This will make that thread more efficient.

**Shutting Down**

You can kill a Process with a signal, but it's harder (really impossible) to kill a thread. Your shutdown
routine will depend on how you want to handle items which are still in the queue.

If you don't care about processing items remaining in the queue when shutting down, you can
simply send a TERM signal to the child process and exit the main thread. Since the listener
thread has its `.daemon` attribute set to True it will also exit.

If you do care about processing items in the queue at shutdown time, you should
inform the listener thread to exit its processing loop by sending a special *sentinel* value
and then joining on that thread to wait for it to exit.

Here is an example which incorporates the above ideas. I haven chosen `None` for
the sentinel value.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep
from random import random
import os
import signal

def child_process(q):
  i = 1
  while True:
    q.put(i)
    i += 1
    sleep( random() )

def listener_thread(q, callback):
  while True:
    item = q.get()   # this will block until an item is ready
    if item is None:
      break
    callback(item)

def doit(item):
  print "got:", item

def main():
  q = Queue()

  # start up the child process:
  child = Process(target=child_process, args=(q,))
  child.start()

  # start up the listener
  listener = Thread(target=listener_thread, args=(q,doit))
  listener.daemon = True
  listener.start()

  sleep(5)
  print "Exiting"
  os.kill( child.pid, signal.SIGTERM )
  q.put(None)
  listener.join()

main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ErikR. Your code is simpler, more readable, and more efficient with the blocking get. I don't really understand your exit code.

Comment: With the sentinel stopping the  listener, why would listener.daemon=True not work if we ommit joining the listener?

Comment: Exiting the main thread will stop the listener, but the point of the sentinel is allow the listener to process any items remaining in the queue before exiting. By putting the sentinel on the queue the listener will eventually exit its loop. By calling listener.join() the main thread will wait for the listener to exit.

Comment: using listener.daemon = True and exiting the main thread will also stop the listener.